# graphql, Apollo returning "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" when going to GraphQL endpoint

Tags: reactjs, express, graphql, apollo

I'm working on a project that is utilizing graphql, apollo, and express. When I go to the graphql endpoint I receive a white page with this error in the console [Console log error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqb3J.png)

When I click on the source of this error ('main.js...'), this is what is returned: [main.js error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHj1X.jpg)

This is the full HTML response returned there.

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/><title>React App</title><script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.39472c11.js"></script><link href="./static/css/main.073c9b0a.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

I have dug around a lot on the internet and found that this is supposed to be a JSON response, but it's receiving HTML, hence the '<' token (from <!DOCTYPE>), however, I can't for the life of me find where a change needs to be implemented to fix this.

[I believe the issue could be caused by line 44-46.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oKft.jpg) I have defined a graphql route, and it returns in the console upon the server starting (Use GraphQL at http://localhost:3001/graphql) however it seems to be serving up an html file at that route instead. Any help is appreciated, if anyone needs any extra details let me know and I'd be happy to provide. At my wits end with this, and thank you in advance for taking a look!

Edit: Going to add some code that might be causing trouble.

server.js

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
}


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: OP here, I'm leaving this question up as a means of helping someone else who may run into this issue. What solved this issue for me was commenting out these two lines in my server.js file:    

 ```javascript
// app.use(routes);


// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
// });

```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I know this is an older question but I ran into the same issue and found out that by removing the catchall from the app.get("*" .... fixxed it in my case, so yours would be :

`app.get("/", (req, res) => { res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html")); });`

Hope this helps you and anyone that ends up here :)